# Google Play Services Login succeeds on one phone but fails on antoher

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I've successfully implemented Google Play Services in my app. I was following [Accessing the Play Games Services APIs in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) and the login is working on my Sony Xperia Z5 but fails on my old Galaxy S2 with the message: "Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again".

What could cause this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was, that I was using a different account on the other phone and that account wasn't a Test-Account. I just added it to the testers and it works now!
(The app is in developement)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check if you have WiFi connection first. If the problem still presists, try the solution for [this google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/zyvFHi9ezn4)

> Try these simple troubleshooting steps:
>
> 1. Restart your device. It might sound simple, but sometimes that's all it takes to fix the issue.
> 2. If restarting doesn't work, switch between Wi-Fi and mobile data: a. Go to Settings > Wireless & networks. b. Turn Wi-Fi off and mobile
>      data on, and check to see if there's a difference. c. If not, turn
>      mobile data off and Wi-Fi on and see if that works.   If the issue
>      persists, try removing and adding your Google Account to the device.
>      Here's how:
>
> Remove Google Account: Open your device's Settings app. Under
>   "Accounts," touch Google and then the account you want to remove.
>   Touch the Menu icon in the top right corner of the screen. Touch
>   Remove account.
>
> Add Google Account: Open your device's Settings app. Under "Accounts,"
>   touch Add account > Google Google. Follow the instructions to add your
>   account. If needed, repeat steps to add multiple accounts.

Here's a useful Help Center article for more information on fixing [internet connection problems](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2651367?vid=0-189742204927-1496998601163).